# Data model of existing data in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I have a small dataset loaded into Neo4J consisting of a 6 node labels with about 20 nodes for each label and there are about 10 different relationships. I was wondering if you can automatically create a picture of this data model using the data available in the database.

I would like to create something like this automatically from the data:
[image: Data model from]

taken from http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-movie-database.html

I know that it would be quite simple doing it manually in this example but it could come in handy looking at more complex data models.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://neo4j.com/blog/graph-this-rendering-your-graph-with-graphviz/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Michael, that helped. There is also functionality in the web tool that ships with Neo4J that can do something similar although less graphically.

You click on the little bubbles in the top left corner of the interface and then there is a predefined query that extracts all lables and relations from the graph.